htaccess allow any access for subfolder
I have a folder www on my webspace where I defined that an authentication is required:
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter credentials."
AuthUserFile path/htpwd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

In the subfolder www/folder/public/ should be accessible without authentication . Therefore I created the .htaccess
Satisfy Any

Inexplicably if I navigate to www/folder/public/file.php, the authentication is shown. The page is already shown in the background. If no entry is made and log in is clicked on twice. The windows doesn´t show again and the page is fully visible.
What can be the reason? How it can be influenced externally?
I have two other subfolders (www/folder/public_working) with the same htaccess, there it works as desired. For what kind of differences between the directories can I look?

You may use these directives inside www/.htaccess
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/www/public/" OPEN

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter credentials."
AuthUserFile /full/path/htpwd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=OPEN
Satisfy any

You don't need to create another .htaccess directive inside the public/ directory.

still exactly the same behaviour. i assume it interferes with something else...

This is tested code running fine on my local Apache. If /www is not directly under site root then remove ^ from SetEnvIfNoCase command. Make sure when you test it then there is no other .htaccess in subdirectory and and there are no other directives.

Also clear your browser cache completely before testing.
